# what is simple way to access outlook 365 emails via API & PHP

Tags: php, api, outlook

been looking/searching all day and frustrated that I can only find:

- MS or Github code where you MUST install via composer
- examples that have so much code, options, features that its too complicated
- or OLD versions

And for whatever reason, the MS developer site makes it so confusing to me, that it looks so simple, yet all day and don't have a working example yet :(

I have the APP clientID and Secret Key, an outlook 365 email user and their password.

What is the bare minimum, basic code to do this:

a) connect to exchange server 
b) for the given user and echo out some email subjects

If I can make that happen, in a simple (1 php file)... I would be very happy!!

In my struggles, I saw this seems so easy via REST API... but dealing with the auth, tokens, etc. I mean, I don't need or want to login... I can just hard code everything...  I just want to execute the php file and display email subjects.

THANKS... very much appreciate the help
:)

PS. I mean, I'm very confused why I can't figure it out? I must be missing something easy?

Comment: Composer is an important part of the modern PHP ecosystem. I suggest you accept that and try out some of the libraries you found that require it.

Comment: thanks Chris...  The 1st many years of me doing PHP... there was no composer, etc. And I never became a command line guy. So its sad to say, the composer concept is like Greek to me... I'm like... its just php files, there is no "installing" them... just FTP them. done.  But apparently, composer does much more...  surely there are many people like me, who just want to copy the files vs. "installing" them?

as for MS outlook API... why is it so confusing (their documentation, their code examples, etc)  I figured out googles API stuff in minutes... but MS... hours and nothing to show for it

Comment: There's always time to learn, and you don't necessarily have to use the command line. May PHP IDEs support Composer. As to why you find Microsoft's documentation confusing, there's no way to answer that.

Comment: https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/php

QUESTION --- on that page, its showing emails from an exchange user, BUT NO Password to the account was ever entered?  what am I missing?

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow need to be focused and self-contained. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], then read [ask] for tips on asking effective questions. "What is a simple way to do X?" is too broad and primarily opinion-based. "Why can't I figure it out?" is entirely unanswerable. "What is the bare minimum code?" is too broad. Your last comment looks like it's the beginning of a specific question. First, try the code listed on that page. Then, if you're still confused, copy just enough of it here (see [mcve]) to communicate the problem and ask a _clear_ question.

Comment: well, i figured it out, using that tutorial above... it took a several tries, but its working now.

next time I will be more clear :)